# Show that $ax \equiv b (mod\ m) $ has solution iff $gcd(a,m)$ divides $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

Here's what I have:

$ax \equiv b (mod\ m)$ has answer if there are $x$ and $y$ such that

$b = ax + my$

Let $d = gcd(a,m)$. Then:

$d|a$ and $d|m \Leftrightarrow d|ax$ and $d|my \Leftrightarrow d|(ax+my)$

Since $m$ divides the right part of the equation, it also has to divide the left part.

Is this a valid proof for what I want?

Comment: You have half of it: "If there is a solution, then d divides b." You also need to show that whenever b is a multiple of d, you have a solution.

Comment: I see.. Any hints?

Comment: Have you seen yet that the gcd of a and m is a linear combination of them?

Comment: Yes, that's what DonAntonio used bellow, I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;d=gcd(a,m)\;$, then there exist $\;r,s\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. $\;ra+sm=d\;$ , so

$$b=cd\implies b=c(ra+sm)=a(cr)+m(cs)$$

and we have a solution.

Comment: That completes my proof, as Chessnator said above, I've done only half of it. Now, how does that show we have a solution?

Comment: @dumb_undergrad I don't understand: in the above it is clear that $\;x=cr,\,y=cs\;$ is a solution...

Comment: Oh, right, thanks!